# add new system attribute in magento

Tags: magento

I want to add a new attribute named 'category' as system attribute which will be available in all attribute set.Can anybody help me...please give me solution how to do this...thanks

Comment: Does this not create confusion with the normal category system? Would you care to explain the requirements? What is it that cannot be done with the help of a normal attribute?

Comment: just like name,description..i want add one more attribute in system attribute list,so that it will remain visible for all attribute set like system attributes for catalog products.

Comment: 9 questions in 14 days.  No answers accepted.  Give something back to the guys that are keeping you in your day job? </rant>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it by mysql setup file of your custom module. Here is the link of an article which has the code to add attribute:-

[**Magento: Adding attribute from MySql setup file**](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-adding-attribute-from-mysql-setup-file/)

In the above link article, you will see

> 'user_defined' => true,

For creating **system attribute**, you have to make it

> 'user_defined' => false,

Thanks.

Comment: Also, "Vote Up" the answers you like (If you find the answer is useful). Just click the "up arrow sign" present just above the answer points.

Comment: finally...i solved my problem...your article was helpful..thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the only way to add a system attribute is to do it through database call. You will need to write extension that includes setup installation script for SQL (see any core extension for examples) and use addAttribute method.